# Unbound classpasth container: 'JRE System Library[JavaSE-19]' in project 'name'

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm working on a new computer and I`m getting an error I never had before when creating a Java project on Eclipse (The one in the title).

I've done a little research and the error can be fixed by going to Project > Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries, then remove the one is causing the error and adding JRE System Library (I don't really understand why it works in the first place).

But this only fixes the problem for this project, if I were to create a new one it will happen again.

Is there any global configuration I can apply to fix it? Thanks :)

[image: this is the error I get]

Comment: Probably "Preferences > Java > Installed JREs > Execution Environments" Select JavaSE-19 and choose the appropriate JRE.